# Get Current Visitor Id form Vistior Collection Magento2

Tags: magento2

How i can get Current Visitor id Form visitor collection?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code in your class -

```
protected $session;

 public function __construct(
  ...
  \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
  ...
 )
 {
   ...
   $this->session = $session;
   ...
 }

 public function yourFunction()
 {
    $visitor = $this->session->getVisitorData();
    print_r($visitor);
 }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I used this in rest api and it returned me empty array, do you know why?

Comment: @YomnaMansour, can you post a code snippet here of your rest api ?

Comment: `$visitor = $this->session->getVisitorData();
return $visitor;`

Comment: @YomnaMansour did you find any solution I am also using API

Answer (score 0):

The visitor_id is stored in core/session object.

You can reach this way.

Of course ObjectManager is only for testing purposes.
You must code properly via Block, Model, etc, as you prefer.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager');
var_dump($session->getData());
```

Will return something like:

array(2) { ["_form_key"]=> string(16) "qvg5frewPzNpfD1I" ["visitor_data"]=> array(3) { ["last_visit_at"]=> string(19) "2022-06-17 22:44:05" ["session_id"]=> string(26) "vltiv89hgg77v0nlho51v5eevn" ["visitor_id"]=> string(7) "3890947" } }